# Add array with name that is in a variable

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am making a program in node.js (JavaScript) and i want it to make an array with the name that is in a variable, So something like this

```
const name = "test"
const name = ["Contents", "Here"]; // Trying to make an array called the name 
// stored in the "name" variable
```

Thanks!

Comment: so, in the above case, you want to create a `const` called `test`?

Comment: `global[name] = ["Contents", "Here"];` ?

Comment: @JaromandaX Yeah, but ick!

Comment: yeah, but that's what he wants to do

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with a property name in an object. But, AFAIK, you'd need something like an `eval()` to do it with an array (and you shouldn't use `eval()`).

Here's how it would go with an object:

```js
var myObject = {};
const name = "test"
myObject[name] = ["Contents", "Here"]; 

// Test
console.log(myObject.test);
console.log(myObject[name]);
console.log("Does object have a 'test' property? " + (name in myObject && name === "test"));
```

Comment: Why not make `myObject` const, too?

Comment: @melpomene Just a quick example using OPs code. Doesn't really affect the answer.

Comment: @melpomene—why make *name* a *const* at all?

Comment: @RobG Because everything should be as const as possible. Only marking variables as `var` (or better `let`) if you want to modify them later helps avoiding bugs.

Comment: @melpomene Well, that's an opinion that has merit. But, a case could be made for the opposite. Regardless, you can't expect all answers on SO to be 100% perfect in every regard when certain conventions are not relevant to the answer.

Comment: @melpomene—I have never had a bug that would have been avoided by using *const* instead of *var*, but that's just my limited experience. The OP has a bug *caused* by *const* (thought it is likely only pseudo code). ;-)

Answer (score -1):

```
const var_name = "test"
const arr_name.push(var_name);
console.log(arr_name)?
```

I don't be sure that This code will meet your demand.